# Scaling limit, renormalization group and low-energy effective field theories

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, conformal-field-theory, effective-field-theory, scaling

Given a quantum lattice theory $T_0$, e.g., in one dimension defined on $L$ sites, I know that there is a scaling limit, which introduces a lattice scale $a_0$ and keeps the following two quantities fixed:
\begin{eqnarray}
l\equiv La_0,\text{ and }\xi\text{ fixed, as }a_0\rightarrow0.
\end{eqnarray}
Namely, the "physical" length $l$ is fixed while the sites are denser and denser, and various lattice coupling terms are running so that the dimensionful correlation length $\xi$ is fixed. Here the (dimensionless) lattice correlation length $\xi/a_0$ necessarily goes to infinity under the scaling limit above.

After this limit is taken, the space is continuous with length $l$ and the theory under this limit might be a field theory.

My first question: under what condition, the limit above defines a well-defined field theory, i.e. having a finite number of (finite(?)) coupling constants?

The second question: what is the relationship between this scaling limit and the renormalization group?

The third question: if the original lattice theory $T_0$ we start with at the beginning is a critical lattice theory (with a divergent correlation length as $L\rightarrow\infty$), I heard that its low-energy effective theory is described by a conformal field theory (CFT). But is the field theory obtained by the scaling limit above exactly that CFT in the low-energy description? If not, how could we obtain the low-energy CFT which is a field theory on a continuous spacetime?